# Graph plotting: only keeping most relevant data

Tags: algorithm, graph

In order to save bandwith and so as to not to have generate pictures/graphs ourselves I plan on using Google's charting API:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

which works by simply issuing a (potentially long) GET (or a POST) and then Google generate and serve the graph themselves.

As of now I've got graphs made of about two thousands entries and I'd like to trim this down to some arbitrary number of entries (e.g. by keeping only 50% of the original entries, or 10% of the original entries).

How can I decide which entries I should keep so as to have my new graph the closest to the original graph?

Is this some kind of curve-fitting problem?

*Note that I know that I can do POST to Google's chart API with up to 16K of data and this may be enough for my needs, but I'm still curious*

Answer (score 7):

The [**flot-downsample plugin**](https://github.com/sveinn-steinarsson/flot-downsample/) for the Flot JavaScript graphing library could do what you are looking for, up to a point.

> The purpose is to try retain the visual characteristics of the original line using considerably fewer data points.

The research behind this algorithm is documented [in the author's thesis](http://skemman.is/stream/get/1946/15343/37285/3/SS_MSthesis.pdf).

Note that it doesn't work for any kind of series, and won't give meaningful results when you want a downsampling factor beyond 10, in my experience.

The problem is that it cuts the series in windows of equal sizes then keep one point per window. Since you may have denser data in some windows than others the result is not necessarily optimal. But it's efficient (runs in linear time).

Comment: There is a great list of implementations for other programming languages/frameworks in the [README](https://github.com/sveinn-steinarsson/flot-downsample/#the-algorithm-lttb-adapted-for-other-programming-languages-or-frameworks).

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking to do is known as *downsampling* or *decimation*. Essentially you filter the data and then drop N - 1 out of every N samples (decimation or down-sampling by factor of N). A crude filter is just taking a local moving average. E.g. if you want to decimate by a factor of N = 10 then replace every 10 points by the average of those 10 points.

Note that with the above scheme you may lose some high frequency data from your plot (since you are effectively low pass filtering the data) - if it's important to see short term variability then an alternative approach is to plot every N points as a single vertical bar which represents the *range* (i.e. min..max) of those N points.

Comment: No, this doesn't keep the new graph as close to the original. In fact, you may lose all the relevant data (which may be only a segment of X points). If the OP means to do serious "relevant data", this is not the solution.

Comment: Which of the above two proposed solutions are you referring to ? Downsampling/decimation or plotting ranges ?

Comment: In both of them you're simply modifying the data, which, at least for statisticians, is always a no-no, because the points "are not real data points". If you want to keep the "spirit" of the graph, these methods won't do, you need a more intelligent approach. If, however, data faithfulness is not important to the OP, then yes, this simple methods will do.

Comment: @Dervin Thunk: I stated that I wanted to keep the new graph "close" to the original, not identical.  Of course I'm modifying the data, that's kinda the whole point of my question...

Comment: @Syntax: and I'm saying there is a method not to do that. Depending on what you do, my method could be overkill... my results tend to affect country-wide policies... :S

Comment: Well since you are reducing the number of data points then whatever method you use you must be losing *some* information. Depending on the nature of the data you need to decide what information you want to keep and what you can afford to lose. The above two methods are fine for many applications, but I'm sure there must be exceptions. Perhaps you could share some alternate methods ?

Comment: @Paul R: +1... Yup indeed *"downsampling"* seems to be exactly what I'm after.  With that search term, I already found some Java APIs doing what I think is what I'm after.  However I'm looking for something more complex than simply smoothing out my data by using a crude average every *n* point.

Comment: @Paul... no, no... I don't seem to be explaining myself properly: I'm saying my methods have a *principled methodology* of what the some information I'm losing is. Your methods are across the board, and that's what bad, IMO.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: a moving average is just a very poor low pass filter - you can use better filters, depending on how accurate you would like your downsampled representation to be. Size of the filter will depend on your decimation factor, N.

Comment: @Dervin: I think you're assuming requirements that are perhaps not valid in this case. It may be that you have one specific method that is important to you, but in the general case most people are not interested in high frequency components (which are typically just noise) when they are creating a graphical overview representation.

Answer (score 1):

Graph (time series data) summarization is a very hard problem. It's like deciding, in a text, what is the "relevant" part to keep in an automatic summarization of it. I suggest you use one of the most respected libraries for finding "patterns of interest" in time series data by [Eamonn Keogh](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/)