# Display huge amount of data with jquery Flot

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm developing a web application using Jquery/Flot plugin and I need to diplay some timeseries of 30.000 datapoints. I'm experiencing permormance issues (with all browsers) due to the huge amount of datas. Of course I don't need to diplay ALL the datapoints, it would be impossible with a 400px chart. My general idea is to only display "the most significant data" so I need a best practice/suggestion to preserve good performance and a decent chart accuracy

Comment: I'm also thinking at server-side downsampling (I have PHP server-side) to reduce bandwidth usage

Comment: not sure what sort of answer you are expecting other than the obvious...send less data

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674544/graph-plotting-only-keeping-most-relevant-data

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607489/jquery-flot-slow-freezes-ie

Answer (score 2):

If your chart is 400px wide, then your server-side code shouldn't send more than 400 points to the browser.

So if you had time-series data with a point every minute, for example, then one solution would be to average all the values for an hour, taking your 30k points down to 500.  That would be pretty easy if the data was coming out of a database; your query might look roughly like this:

```
SELECT truncate_to_hour(data_time) as sample_time, avg(data_value)
FROM values
GROUP BY sample_time
```

But obviously there's no single best-practice; it depends on your data.

Comment: I'd take it a step further, and say that having 1 point per pixel is too much, it should be more like 3 pixels per point (400/3=133), but 5 would be ideal (400/5=80).  Keep in mind each point in the Flot graph uses more than 1 pixel so visually, 400 is un-usable.

Comment: In theory you can benefit from up to 1ppp - imagine some kind of curvy spline - but you're right that in most real-world use-cases you want at least a few pixels between each point.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but when a point on a FLOT graph is physically bigger than 1 pixel, you won't be able to accurately mouse hover them, or see them properly, hence why I say 3, maybe even 5 pixels per point.